Is there any way to pre-process a .ts file in m3u8 and then decide whether to play or skip it in iOS AVPlayer?
I could not find a way to fetch ts data from m3u8 when AVPlayer is playing, and I do not know whether I can make AVPlayer skip some ts file if I find the ts file is ads.
The reason I want to get ts file is that I would like to process the ts stream data by AI, if it is
a commercial ad, then I tell AVPlayer skip it.
I have made a tflite model, works well, but I am stuck in pre-process the streaming data, the documentation just shows example how to play m3u8 file by AVPlayer, and how to download it.
I need to find a way to pre-process such HTTP live streaming media, and make AVPlayer skip ads in streaming.
